# mysql - search timestamp by hour of day

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a column named `updatetime` that is a `timestamp`. So, for example, an average looking value could be: `2011-02-01 09:00:51`. I want to be able to search through and return all results for a particular hour of the day regardless of the date.

For example if I searched the column for values `BETWEEN 09:00:00 AND 09:59:99` it would return:

```
2011-02-01 09:00:51
2011-01-31 09:20:51
2011-01-11 09:55:44
etc....
```

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE updatetime ......`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use the [HOUR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) function:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE HOUR(`updatetime`) = 9
```

Alas, this query's performance will be *horrible*, as soon as you go over a few thousand rows - functions aren't indexable, so there will be a full table scan each time this query runs.

What we did in a similar situation: we created another column `updatetime_hour`, indexed it, and populated it on insert (and updated on update); then the query becomes fast:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE `updatetime_hour` = 9
```

Yes, we have denormalized the data, and it's a bit more housekeeping, but I have yet to see a faster solution. (We considered and measured insert and update triggers to populate the `updatetime_hour` from `updatetime`, but decided against for performance; see if they would be useful for you.)

Comment: Good point about the performance. I can implement an indexed hour column on insert easy enough, but any ideas on how to go through my previous 60k rows and UPDATE with 'updatetime_hour' column data?

Comment: @user410341: During off-peak hours, and very carefully ;) `UPDATE yourtable SET updatetime_hour=HOUR(updatetime);` <-- this will take a while

Comment: thanks, I just posted as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866056/mysql-create-indexed-hour-column-from-existing-timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`HOUR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE HOUR(updatetime) = 9;
```

This will return all rows between 09:00:00 and 09:59:59.

The `HOUR()` just returns the hour part of the date.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE hour('updatetime') = 9;
```

Would return 9am..

Answer (score 0):

Possibility:
`SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE HOUR(updatetime)='09';`

Answer (score 0):

These answers do not work, this is what worked for me only

```
SELECT hour(FROM_UNIXTIME(`updatetime`)) AS date_formatted FROM `table` where hour(FROM_UNIXTIME(`updatetime`))='9'
```