# mysql - create indexed hour column from existing timestamp

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have a column 'updatetime' that is a timestamp ("2011-02-01 09:00:51"). For performance purposes I need to create an indexed column 'updatetime_hour' based on the hour of the timestamp.

So for example if 'updatetime' was "2011-02-01 09:00:51" then 'updatetime_hour' would be "9".

I'm trying to do this all in mysql though PHP is an option as well. 60k+ existing rows.

Thoughts?

Comment: I thought you said you could do this pretty easily? i.e. Without having to ask another question?

Comment: this is for updating the existing 60k rows, not inserting new rows (which is what I said I could do easily).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourtable SET updatetime_hour=HOUR(updatetime);
```

Don't run this in peak hours, it will take a while. You could even run it in smaller batches - make `updatetime_hour` nullable and continue running this, until you get "0 rows affected":

```
UPDATE yourtable SET updatetime_hour=HOUR(updatetime)
   WHERE updatetime_hour IS NULL LIMIT 1000;
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this automatically each time you add or update a row, use triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1 BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.updatetime_hour = HOUR(NEW.updatetime);
END
CREATE TRIGGER t2 BEFORE UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.updatetime_hour = HOUR(NEW.updatetime);
END
```

Comment: This will not apply to existing rows, but you have a good point. Will +1 when I get my votes back.