# SQL where time in timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have records like:

```
2017-07-24 16:59:32
2017-07-24 17:53:38
2017-07-24 22:26:08
2017-07-24 23:04:54
2017-07-25 08:33:43
2017-07-25 10:06:47
```

And I want to write an sql query which compares only the time part of timestamp, as example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '17:30:00' and '22:30:00'
```

Check only the time and ignore the date. Is it possible to do so?

I'm using MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE hour('date') = 9;
```

Takes full hour, as I sometimes need to take only half of an hour.

Comment: use `hour(date) between 17 and 22`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql - search timestamp by hour of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865753/mysql-search-timestamp-by-hour-of-day)

Comment: In that case it shows how to take between one hour, not a full time.

Comment: and it takes full hour, as I sometimes only need half of an hour.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala but it will take 17:10:00 and 22:40:00 as example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
(HOUR(date) BETWEEN 18 AND 21) OR
(HOUR(date) = 17 AND MINUTE(date)>=30) OR
(HOUR(date) = 22 AND MINUTE(date)<=30);
```

Or another approach would be to convert to `DATE`, add the hours and minutes and then use between.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN
ADDDATE(ADDDATE(DATE(date), INTERVAL 17 HOUR), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
AND
ADDDATE(ADDDATE(DATE(date), INTERVAL 22 HOUR), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: @semkius Sorry, there was a superfluous bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `DATETIME` to a time and use that in the comparison.

Given the sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
  Column1 VARCHAR(50),
  Column2 VARCHAR(50),
  Timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO
Table1
(Column1, Column2, Timestamp)
VALUES
('Valid', 'Time', '2017-01-01 17:43:01'),
('Invalid', 'Time', '2017-01-01 16:00:43');
```

You could query it like the following:

```
SELECT
  *,
  DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%H:%i:%s') AS Time
FROM
  Table1
WHERE
  DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '17:30:00' AND '22:30:00';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfd647/6)

Comment: BETWEEN '17:30:00' AND '08:30:00'; , when I try this I only get between 17:30 and 23:30, why is that?

Comment: I don't think you can overlap midnight like that. You probably have to do (BETWEEN '17:30:00' AND '23:59:59') OR (BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '08:30:00')